# What's the difficulty to detect Were-beings with Shintao/Kenning?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-20th-anniversary, changeling-20th-anniversary

The Wording for Shentao and Kenning is a little ambiguous and I need a little help here:

> Shentao
>
> Much like Kenning, which it replaces, Shentao represents
> the innate magical sense common to the Shinma. It allows
> them to sense each other, dragon nests, and dragon lines, and
> to detect those who hunt them. Shentao may be used to assess
> changelings at a +2 difficulty. Kithain suffer a similar difficulty
> when using Kenning on Shinma.
>
> OOO Competent: You’re able to reliably spot other Hsien,
> regardless of whether they want to be found.

Hsien is the term for pretty much any supernatural being. While Shentao replaces Kenning, Kenning on the other hand refers to such as Prodigals:

> Kenning
>
> Kenning is faerie sight. It allows a character to sense Glamour
> in all of its forms. He can recognize the power of cantrips
> and freeholds, identify “slumbering” changelings, and even
> discover the elusive prodigals and their magic.

Yet, that seems to be all the guidance there is about what level of skill one needs to have in either of the two skills to detect what Werewolf calls a Bête - any of the Shapechanging Were-beings.

What is the general difficulty for this roll and is there a number of successes needed akin to the Werewolf "Scent of the true Form"?